# Rails: Forum has_many topics, saving the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, routes, belongs-to

I might be going about this the wrong way in the first place, so I will give a bit of background first.

As you can tell from the title, I am building a forum from scratch. I thought it was working correctly; however, I am a bit unsure as to how to update/save the forum object from within the topics "create" method in it's controller.

What I tried to do:
In the "New" method, I sent the Forum's id via the routing. So on the new-topic page has a address that looks like this: "localhost:3000/new-topic/1". The one being the Forum's id. In the method itself, I try to attach it to the new topic object.

```
@topic = Topic.new
@topic.forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
```

My create method then tries to use that forum.

```
@topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
@topic.forum.topics << @topic #Simplified down.
if @topic.save
  @topic.forum.save
...
```

I get the feeling that I am going about this the wrong way. I was looking at someone's tutorial and they got the forum by calling params[:forum_id] but they didn't show they routing they did to achieve that.

How do I do this correctly and/or what is the correct way to route all of this? For the record, I do plan on using this same method for the Topic => Post association. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested REST routes:

```
# routes.rb
resources :forums do
  resources :topics
end
```

this will result in the following routes:

```
GET  /forums/:forum_id/topics/new # displays the form
POST /forums/:forum_id/topics     # creates the topic
```

and in controller you should use builders, they have several advantages like security, scope preserving etc.:

```
def new
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = @forum.topics.build

def create
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @topic = @forum.topics.build(params[:topic])
  if @topic.save
    ...
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! This is exactly the kind of explanation that I was looking for!

Comment: I got that to work for the forum -> Topic relationship. But what about the Topic -> Post? I did a double nested resource. And that is working up until I try to make the form. form_for [@forum, @topic, @post] do |f| doesnt work for me.

Comment: It is advised to never nest resources more than 1 level deep.